# python error message mentioning "tuple" without any tuples existing in code

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

From the following xml data (in the file lieferungen.xml):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <lieferungen xmlns="urn:myspace:lieferungen"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="urn:myspace:lieferungen C:\xml\lieferungen.xsd">
        <artikel id="3526">
            <name>apfel</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="true">8.97</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="7866">
            <lieferant>Fa. Helbig</lieferant>
            <name>Kirschen</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="false">10.45</preis>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="4444"> <!--DIFFERENT ID FOR apfel!! -->    
            <name>apfel</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="true">12.67</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Liebig</lieferant>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="7866">
            <preis stueckpreis="false">17.67</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Krause</lieferant>
            <name>Kirschen</name>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="2345"> <!--DIFFERENT ID FOR apfel!! -->
            <name>apfel</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="true">9.54</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Mertes</lieferant>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="7116"> <!--DIFFERENT ID FOR Kirschen!! -->
            <name>Kirschen</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="false">16.45</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="7868">
            <name>Kohl</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="false">3.20</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="7866">
            <name>Kirschen</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="false">12.45</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="3245">
            <name>Bananen</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="false">15.67</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Hoeller</lieferant>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="6745"> <!--DIFFERENT ID FOR Kohl!! -->     
            <name>Kohl</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="false">3.10</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Reinhardt</lieferant>
        </artikel>
        <artikel id="7789">
            <name>Ananas</name>
            <preis stueckpreis="true">8.60</preis>
            <lieferant>Fa. Richard</lieferant>
        </artikel>
     </lieferungen>
```

I want to create the following output:

```
<html><head><title>Lieferungen</title></head>
<body><h1>Lieferungen</h1><hr>

<table border="1"><tr><th>Nummer</th><th>Artikel</th><th>preis</th><th>Lieferant</th></tr>
<tr><td>3526</td> <td> apfel </td> <td> 8.97 </td> <td> Fa. Krause </td> </tr>
<tr><td>7866</td> <td> Kirschen </td> <td> 10.45 </td> <td> Fa. Helbig </td> </tr>
<tr><td>3526</td> <td> apfel </td> <td> 12.67 </td> <td> Fa. Liebig </td> </tr>
<tr><td>7866</td> <td> Kirschen </td> <td> 17.67 </td> <td> Fa. Krause </td> </tr>
<tr><td>3526</td> <td> apfel </td> <td> 9.54 </td> <td> Fa. Mertes </td> </tr>
<tr><td>7866</td> <td> Kirschen </td> <td> 16.45 </td> <td> Fa. Hoeller </td> </tr>
<tr><td>7868</td> <td> Kohl </td> <td> 3.20 </td> <td> Fa. Hoeller </td> </tr>
<tr><td>7866</td> <td> Kirschen </td> <td> 12.45 </td> <td> Fa. Richard </td> </tr>
<tr><td>3245</td> <td> Bananen </td> <td> 15.67 </td> <td> Fa. Hoeller </td> </tr>
<tr><td>6745</td> <td> Kohl </td> <td> 3.10 </td> <td> Fa. Reinhardt </td> </tr>
<tr><td>7789</td> <td> Ananas </td> <td> 8.60 </td> <td> Fa. Richard </td> </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

To this end I wrote the following python program:

```
import xml.dom.minidom 

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse("lieferungen.xml")


print("<html><head><title>Lieferungen</title></head>")
print("<body><h1>Lieferungen</h1><hr>\n")
print("<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Nummer</th><th>Artikel</th><th>preis</th><th>Lieferant</th></tr>") 

artikel = dom.getElementsByTagName("artikel")


for i in range(artikel.length):
    print("<tr><td>{}</td>".format(artikel[i].getAttribute("id")), end="")

    # initialize the variables name, preis und lieferant to artikel[i].childNodes[0]
    # the variables could also be initialized to, say, artikel[i].childNodes[1] 
    # but they need to be initialized to this particular datatype, otherwise python would
    # complain when trying to do: tags = [name, preis, lieferant]
    name = artikel[i].childNodes[0]
    preis = artikel[i].childNodes[0]
    lieferant = artikel[i].childNodes[0]

    for j in range(artikel[i].childNodes.length):
        if artikel[i].childNodes[j].nodeName == "name":
            name = artikel[i].childNodes[j]
        elif artikel[i].childNodes[j].nodeName == "preis":
            preis = artikel[i].childNodes[j]
        elif artikel[i].childNodes[j].nodeName == "lieferant":
            lieferant = artikel[i].childNodes[j]    

        tags = [name, preis, lieferant]
        for tag in tags:
            print("<td>{}</td>".format(tag.childNodes[0].nodeValue), end="")


    print("</tr>")  


print("</table>")
print("")
print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

When running this program, it results in the following error message:

```
print("<td>{}</td>".format(tag.childNodes[0].nodeValue), end="")
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I don't understand this error message. There is not even a tuple in my code. So how can a tuple index be out of range?

Comment: `tag.childNodes` is a tuple (an empty one, apparently); there **is** a tuple in your code.

Comment: Seems to me if `name` is already a list (`artikel[i].childNodes[j]`) then `format(tag.childNodes[0].nodeValue)` is incorrect. Shouldn't that be  just `format(tag.nodeValue)`?